# Black-Scholes PDE derivation

Tags: option-pricing

In reviewing  Black and Scholes original derivation of their partial differential equation for pricing a call option (Journal of Political Economy, Vol. 81, No. 3, 1973, p. 642) it would seem that they tacitly (and conveniently) assumed that
$w_1$ is constant:
$$ \Delta V  = \Delta x - \Delta (w/w_1) = \Delta x - \Delta(w)/w_1.
$$
But in general $\Delta (a/b) \ne \Delta(a)/b$ unless $b$ is constant.
 If that assumption is not made, then the resulting partial differential equation would be significantly more complicated, in fact 3rd order and nonlinear.  What am I missing?

Comment: You mean the partial derivative of price wrt the first argument which they represent by $w_1(x,t)$ with $w(x,t)$ representing the option price?

Comment: Yes, $w_1(x,t) = w_x(x,t)$.

Comment: Your intuition that something is wrong in that part of the original paper is correct. The number of options in the hedge portfolio has to be time-varying in order for the portfolio to be self-financing. It turns out that the additional capital needed is zero on average though. There is a nice discussion of this issue in Section 3.1.10 of Musiela and Rutkowski’s great book “Martingale Methods in Financial Modelling”.

Answer (score -1):

Black and Scholes' PDE  derivation (Journal of Political Economy, Vol. 81, no. 3, 1973, p. 642) glossed over the fact that 
$\frac{d}{dt}(w_1) \ne 0$. In the following I   use $w_x$ notation rather than $w_1$.  Re-working the derivation starting from the risk-free hedging condition, 
\begin{eqnarray*}
E(\frac{d}{dt}(x-w/w_x))  & = & r (x-w/w_x),   
\end{eqnarray*}
letting $\mu$ be the drift where $ \mu x = E(\frac{dx}{dt})$,
expanding and correcting for Black-Scholes'  omission:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mu x- \frac{w_x \left[w_x \mu x + w_t  + \mbox{$\frac{1}{2}$} x^2\sigma^2 w_{xx}\right]
- w\left[w_{xx} \mu x + w_{xt} + \mbox{$\frac{1}{2}$} x^2 \sigma^2 w_{xxx}\right]}{ w_x^2 }  \nonumber \\
=  r(x - w/w_x). 
\end{eqnarray*}
In this equation  $\mu$ appears in three places. Clearly, the first two involve terms that  exactly cancel  each other, which leads to the commonly held assertion that the drift, $\mu$, is irrelevant for pricing options. But this irrelevance holds only if the third place where $\mu$ appears also drops out of the picture, which is not true in general. 
Simplifying,
\begin{eqnarray*}
 -w_x \left[ w_t  + \mbox{$\frac{1}{2}$} x^2\sigma^2 w_{xx}\right]
+ w\left[w_{xx} \mu x + w_{xt} + \mbox{$\frac{1}{2}$} x^2 \sigma^2 w_{xxx}\right]  \\
=  w_x^2 r (x - w/w_x). 
\end{eqnarray*}
Simplifying further and re-arranging,
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \left[r x w_x +w_t  + \mbox{$\frac{1}{2}$} x^2 \sigma^2 w_{xx} -  r w\right]  
   - \left[w /w_x (w_{xx} \mu x + w_{xt} + \mbox{$\frac{1}{2}$} x^2 \sigma^2 w_{xxx})\right] 
 = 0.  
\end{eqnarray*}
If the second term in brackets is $0$, then the Black-Scholes PDE results.  Thus, the Black-Scholes PDE might be taken as an   approximating PDE (second order and linear) to  the true  PDE (third order and nonlinear) that governs call option prices.
 Clearly, the  relevance of $\mu$ for pricing call options in this PDE does not simply evaporate, although it does evaporate in the Black-Scholes PDE.